# SQLStatement is getting rejected

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a user note into a sqliteDB through this method but for some reason, its not passing this `if` statement...

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){}
```

I'm not sure but I think my SQLStatement is getting rejected or some reason.

```
(void) insertQuickNoteInDataBase:(NSString *)name :(NSString *)note{
sqlite3 * database;

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    const char *sqlStatement = "insert into detail(QuickNote) values (?), where name = ?";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 8, [note UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, [name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(compiledStatement))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to log the error using `sqlite3_errmsg`. But the problem is most likely the comma in the query as well as the `where` clause. Insert statements should not have a `where` clause. Perhaps you mean to use an update:

```
"UPDATE detail SET QuickNote = ? WHERE name = ?"
```

Also, your calls to `sqlite3_bind_xxx` need to have the proper indexes. The bind indexes start at 1 and go up. You are using 8 then 2. You want 1 then 2.

Comment: You got that right, i was suppose to use "Update" instead of "insert into" in the statement, i just tried again and it's working great! Thanks rmaddy

Comment: rmaddy - is it the correct statement to get the value back from DB  "select (QuickNote) from detail where name = ?"  ??